# Hyphened 3 words route getting broken in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, routes

A web route

```php
Route::get('/commercial-real-estate', [App\Http\Controllers\CommController::class, 'listing']);
```

is going to https://example.com/estate/commercial-real

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is the route displayed on the artisan command prompt? ``php artisan route:list``

Comment: GET|HEAD | commercial-real-estate                      |                  | App\Http\Controllers\CommController@listing                            | web        |

Comment: The route seems OK, what if you try to access your route directly  https://example.com/estate/commercial-real-estate, can you share the HTML where you're displaying the URL?

Comment: If I try to access it directly it revert back to the same as above. It the same with /residential-real-estate. But farms-for-sale works fine

Comment: HTML
<li class="nav-item"><a href="/commercial-real-estate" class="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-industry"></i> Commercial Real Estate</a></li>

Comment: Something is odd, update your post, share your logs and your ``web.php``.

Comment: for the moment I am moving forward with just /Commercial link. Will investigate it later and update this post. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

composer dump-autoload solved the problem. Thank you guys for your support.